# GemFire CacheLoader from Cassandra

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

In my project using GemFire with Cassandra, my `CacheLoader` was able to pull data from Cassandra, however, the data was not available in GemFire.  After getting the data from Cassandra, the data is not being updated in GemFire.

I have used code below:

```
public class TestLoader implements CacheLoader, Declarable {

    @Autowired
    private CassandraOperations cassandraOperations;

    @Override
    public void init(Properties props) {}

    @Override
    public Test load(LoaderHelper helper) {
        String key = (String) helper.getKey();
        key = key.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        Select select = QueryBuilder.select().from("Testing");
        select.where(QueryBuilder.eq(testkey, key));
        return cassandraOperations.selectOne(select, TEST.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {}
}
```

Test - Domain class Name
Testing - Cassandra Table name
testkey - Cassandra primary key

[image]

Comment: doc here: https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/outside_data_sources/implementing_data_loaders.html From the look of your implementation, it looks alright. I would suspect there is some problem with your wiring. Could you please share more details, e.g. how do you configure CacheLoader, whats your clustor setup etc.

Comment: @Vigneshwaran : your issue is resolved ? I am experiencing same behavior like you have mentioned in your table with partition region and proxy

Answer (score 1):

So, your `CacheLoader` appears to be fine, other than the `select.where(..)` statement, which should read `select.where(QueryBuilder.eq("testkey", key));`.  Clearly this code would not compile.  Beyond this, though, I too am curious about your configuration and topology as **Xiawei Zhang** points out in the comment above.  Clearly you are using a client/server topology, but the extent of which is not apparent, nor is your configuration.

You should be registering this `CacheLoader` on the server's cache `PARTITION` *Region*, not on the client *Region* (if that is the case).  Regardless of whether the server cache *Region* is a `PARTITION` or a `PARTITION_REDUNDANT` should not really matter.

However, there is also a lot you need to understand in terms of your topology, which **Xiawei Zhang** also hints at.

In a typical setup, your (cache) client makes a request for a cache entry (by key) in a `PROXY` or `CACHING_PROXY` client *Region*.  If the entry is not available locally or is invalid (in the `CACHING_PROXY` configuration), then the request is forwarded (NOTE: with `PROXY`, the request is always forwarded) to the server having a *Region* by the same name (e.g. "Test").  If the entry is not available in the server's *Region*, and a `CacheLoader` has been registered, then the `CacheLoader` with that key is invoked.  In your case, the data for the entry will be loaded from Cassandra (as shown above) and "put" into the server *Region* using the configured `CacheLoader` (again, must be configured server-side), and then returned to the client.

Now, if you have multiple clients involved (which might possibly be your case), then you need to make sure you have "subscription" enabled, and you need to register interests in the specific key or keys needed by your clients.  Alternatively, you can use CQs (recommended) to define a (GemFire OQL) query predicate to more succinctly express the data you are interested in receiving notifications for.

Subscription is [configured/enabled](http://gemfire-91-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/client/PoolFactory.html#setSubscriptionEnabled-boolean-) on the `Pool` associated with the client `PROXY`|`CACHING_PROXY` *Region* and "interests" (for example, [by key(s)](http://gemfire-91-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#registerInterest-K-org.apache.geode.cache.InterestResultPolicy-boolean-boolean-) or [using regex](http://gemfire-91-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#registerInterestRegex-java.lang.String-org.apache.geode.cache.InterestResultPolicy-boolean-boolean-), with overloaded variants) is expressed with the *Region* API.

You will find more information on *Configuring Client/Server Event Messaging* [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/events/configure_client_server_event_messaging.html).  Additionally, you should consider [Continuous Queries](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/continuous_querying/chapter_overview.html).

You should also make sure you really understand client/server messaging, especially with multiple clients in your topology, by reading [this](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/events/how_client_server_distribution_works.html).

There are other configuration options available, server-side, such as [consistency checking](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/distributed_regions/region_entry_versions.html), especially when you have redundancy configured in your PRs and 1 of your clients may possibly be hitting a redundant copy, but that should be less of an issue here.

Technically, it is more likely to be an issue with your client queue since client queues are updated asynchronously and notifications sent from a server to a client are indeterministic as the documentation points out...

> *5. The event for entry X is sent out of the queue to Client2. When this happens is indeterminate.*

Anyhow, start with this.  Make sure that the request/load/update from a single client is consistent first, then involve other clients.  Make sure you have expressed the right interests policies, etc.  Read the documentation in the links I provided.

Hope this helps!

Regards,
John